# Residuals but no fitted values from a regression model in R

Tags: r, regression

I did a simple regression analysis and wanted to plot the residuals against the fitted values to see their behaviour. Afterwards I wanted to check if the residuals are normally distributed. So I did:

```
summary(lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI))

residuen<-summary(lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI))$residuals
    fitted<-summary(lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI))$fitted.values
plot(fitted,residuen)
```

The problem is, that,

```
summary(lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI))$fitted.values
```

gives `NULL` as a result, so does that mean there are no fitted values? I guess this is due to some missing values, but I don't know. And how can R calculate residudals but not the fitted values?

My data set can be found here: http://www.sendspace.com/file/8e27d0

Comment: the summary doesn't have the fitted values, the model does.

Try `m1 <- lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI)`

Then fitted(m1) or m1$fitted

Answer (score 5):

1. You could make your problem more reproducible by adding `data=olympiadaten` to your code
2. `summary.lm()`, the method the generic `summary()` calls when its argument is of class `lm`, doesn't have `$fitted.values`, but `lm()` does. Try changing `summary(lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI))$fitted.values` to 
   `lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI, data=olympiadaten)$fitted.values`
3. In general you can check out what an object consists of in R by `str()`

Comment: ok thanks, so it is ok, if I check the residuals with the ks test if they are normal distributed right?  @miura

Comment: No, this is not recommended. You should rather take a look at a residuals vs. fitted plot. Try `plot(lm(Gesamt~PopTotal+HDI, data=olympiadaten))`, it's the first of the four plots coming, and it's a bit concerning.

Comment: The second plot shows a normal QQ plot of the residuals which deals with the question of normality of residuals you posed in your comment. It also doesn't look too good. There are many threads here discussing regression diagnostics which you can check out.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32600/in-what-order-should-you-do-linear-regression-diagnostics should help